# MacLaurin polynomial at the third order in three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I don't know how to resolve this:

> Write the Maclaurin polynomial stopped at the third order of the function:
> $f(x,y,z)= 3x - 2yz + z^3 + 2x^4 - x^2y^2$

Should I use the standard formula or is there a shorter way? With the development of the polynomial I have a trinomial squared and cube.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Simplest way is to use the formula. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Just keep the terms where the power of $x$ plus the power of $y$ plus the power of $z$ is less or equal to 3.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I would like to know why is that, in my book there is nothing regarding multi-variable taylor series @gt6989b

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

For example, using Mathematica

`f[x_,y_,z_]:= 3x - 2y z + z^3 + 2x^4 - x^2 y^2`

`Normal[Series[f[x t, y t, z t], {t, 0, 3}]] /. t -> 1`

will produce

`3 x - 2 y z + z^3`

Using

`Normal[Series[f[x t, y t, z t], {t, 0, 4}]] /. t -> 1`

would produce

`3 x + 2 x^4 - x^2 y^2 - 2 y z + z^3`

which is the original function

Comment: I don't understand what you did there, I know how to calculate and use directional derivatives.

Comment: And I thought I was supposed to use this formula (= https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) but in three variables, so I thought it was too long...

Comment: @Iacopo. You just introduce the dummy varaible $t$, you expand the function with respect to $t$ around $t=0$ and you let $t=1$ at the end.

Comment: but I don't know how to use the variable t, what do u mean with t=1 at the end? could u link me something? I linked you the formula I was using before and it's completely different, I would like to know why is that